# Duration class returning incorrect duration between keystrokes

Tags: java, events, duration, keyevent, milliseconds

I'm trying to retrieve the duration of time between keystrokes in milliseconds. In this case, I'm just doing a light tap between the KeyEvents methods keypressed and keyreleased. I'm using the Duration class, and initially it was working, but now it's recording the timespan incorrectly.

I'm recording the time in the keypressed and keyreleased methods, adding the code start = Instant.now(); and end = Instant.now(); to each method, respectively. In the keyreleased class, I then measure the duration by coding

```
Duration span = Duration.between();
long timelapse = span.toMillis();
```

If I debug, the variables in the IDE console show like this:

start = "2022-01-15T05:48:32.065492Z"

end = "2022-01-15T05:48:38.5196766Z"

span = "PT6.454184S" {seconds = 6 ,nanos = 454184000 }

And if I were to retrieve the value of the duration in milliseconds, span.toMillis() = 6454, and I KNOW I didn't hold the key for 6 seconds. It was maybe between 30 and 100 milliseconds.

Is there anything I can do to correct this? And if not, is there another approach to finding accurate duration between keystrokes?

EDIT: I do want to note that these methods are actually measuring the amount of time elapsed between user input. The reason for this is to calculate movement. How long the button was held determines how far an image moves. In this case, where I just give a light tap, I just want the image to change direction without any movement.

I imagine that maybe the duration class is taking longer because I've been adding more and more code for functionality. So what I really hope to do is find the correct time elapsed in the midst of other running classes and methods, if possible.

Comment: Looking at your `start` and `end` timestamps they **are** 6 seconds apart (the second parts are 32 and 38) and therefore the calculation is correct. You should rather check how you take your start and end measurements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Method [keyReleased](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)) is actually called after method `keyTyped`.

In all my experiments, using JDK 17.0.1 on Windows 10, I was unable to successfully record a time in method `keyReleased`. Hence I recorded the end time in method `keyTyped`. The `KeyEvent` parameter for method `keyTyped` has a [getWhen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getWhen()) method that records the time of the key press in milliseconds. (Refer to method [currentTimeMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) in class `java.lang.System`)

Hence, in order to get the duration, I call `System.currentTimeMillis` in method `keyTyped` and subtract that from the value returned by method `getWhen` of class `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`

```
@Override // java.awt.event.KeyListener
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long start = e.getWhen();
    System.out.println("start: " + start);
    System.out.println("  end: " + end);
    System.out.println((end - start) / 1_000.0d);
}
```

Sample output.

```
start: 1642245033174
  end: 1642245033175
0.001
```

Comment: Will this work with other classes and threads running in the background? And when using the keyTyped method, how do I distinguish between lowering and lifting my finger between presses?

Comment: @bds _Will this work with other classes and threads running in the background?_ One way to find out.

Comment: @bds _how do I distinguish between lowering and lifting my finger between presses?_ I don't understand the question. The computer doesn't know that you moved your finger.